# Why are incorrect values being passed between Java and C++ via JNI?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to pass a double value from C++ to Java (Android) using JNI.

Relevant C++ code:

```
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL
Java_test_MPEG_DASH_ffmpeg_PlayerUI_Notif(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,jint st){

    jdouble p=receiver->buffer->Notify();
    LOGI("Notifyyyyyyyyy from jni is %d ",p);
    return p;
}
```

Displays 35, 36, etc

When accessed in Java by calling the native method, the wrong values are returned: 0.0000133333

Relevant Java code:

```
double buf=Notify();
Log.d(TAG, "Bufffffffffffffffffffffffffer :"+buf" ms");
```

Why are the values inconsistent?

Comment: a bit more of code and context could be helpful

Comment: i've edited my post and added the full code

Answer (score 3):

"%d" is not a format specifier compatible with floating point types.  If you use it, you will force a misinterpretation of the bits comprising the jdouble, and print an incorrect value.

It's likely that the value returned to Java is correct (there's a fair amount of type enforcement there), and that being logged incorrect.